# MonthCalendar in C++ CLI .NET

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm trying to make `MonthCalendar` in `C++ CLI`, and I found out how to do that, but when I run my application, there are four `MonthCalendars`. I want just one, and I don't find any method to change that. Only what I can do is change size of calendar (`smaller == less calendars`).
What should I do to make `"n"` calendars in the size what I want?

Making instance of class:

```
this->kalendarz = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MonthCalendar();
```

Initialize object:

```
this->kalendarz = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MonthCalendar();
this->kalendarz->AnnuallyBoldedDates = gcnew cli::array < System::DateTime >(1)
                { System::DateTime(2004,7,4,0,0,0,0)};
this->kalendarz->CalendarDimensions = System::Drawing::Size(2,2);
this->kalendarz->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1,30);
this->kalendarz->MaxSelectionCount = 365;
this->kalendarz->MonthlyBoldedDates = gcnew cli::array < System::DateTime  >(2)
{ System::DateTime(2004,7,4,0,0,0,0), System::DateTime(2004,7,4,0,0,0,0) };
this->kalendarz->Name = L"kalendarz";
this->kalendarz->ShowWeekNumbers = true;
this->kalendarz->Size = System::Drawing::Size(210,297);
this->kalendarz->TabIndex = 3;
```

===============

```
this->kalendarz->Size = System::Drawing::Size(410,297); == 4 calendars
this->kalendarz->Size = System::Drawing::Size(210,297); == 2 calendars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MonthCalendar.SetCalendarDimensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.setcalendardimensions.aspx) should get you what you want:

```
this->kalendarz->SetCalendarDimensions(1, 1);
```

It sets the number of rows and columns of months that should be displayed. Should be the same as this:

```
this->kalendarz->CalendarDimensions = System::Drawing::Size(1, 1);
```

...which I just noticed you have set to `2,2` in your example, so just change those to `1,1`.

Comment: I do that before i ask but that's don't help.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Don't set the Size *after* calling this method.

Comment: Ok now it's working, thank's. First i must set Size and next calendar dimensions.

Comment: How to change Size of the MontCalendar?